# Get print page count without printing the document

Tags: c#, .net, printing, print-preview

This is somewhat similar to question about [Is there a better way to get the page count from a PrintDocument than this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137207/is-there-a-better-way-to-get-the-page-count-from-a-printdocument-than-this)

But in my case I have a web-browser control with formatted html. At the moment I have option which calls `ShowPrintPreviewDialog()` so user can see how many pages going to be printed.

Is there anyway to get the no of pages which going to be printed, without launching the `PrintPreview`?

I am trying to create a method which will call `OnTextChange` and display print-page count automatically?

I have use `PrintPage` event

```
private void PrintDocumentOnPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
 {
     e.Graphics.DrawString(this.webBrowser1.DocumentText, this.webBrowser1.Font, Brushes.Black, 10, 25);               
 }
```

Comment: I think you have your answer in the [answer to the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11456713/1552016): it's a static method you can call in you text change event handler, and it won't display any dialogs at all.

Comment: @qqbenq: if use `StandardPrintController` it works fine but not the `PreviewPrintController`, So the answer doesn't help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bad news always travels slow at SO.  You'll need to scratch the idea that this is practical.

Although unstated in the question, you should have already figured out by now that your PrintPage event handler doesn't work.  It always produces a count of 1.  That's because you never set the `e.HasMorePages` property to true, the property that causes more than one page to be generated.

To *reliably* set that property to true, you need to figure out exactly how the HTML gets rendered by the browser layout engine.  And figure out exactly how to break it up into pages that don't cut, say, a line of text or an image in two.  And figure out how to this is in the **exact** same way that the browser printing engine does this.  A feat that's been attempted by many a programmer, accomplished by none.  The browser's automation object model just doesn't have the needed api.

The only reasonable way is the one you already know.  You *have* to call ShowPrintPreviewDialog().  Which readily displays the page count in the preview dialog, looks like this in IE11:

[image]

In case you'd consider snooping that number off the dialog: no, that cannot work either.  The dialog doesn't use any controls, it is one monolithic window.

Comment: Hi there, where I do really set the `e.NewPage`. I cannot seems to find similar property?

Comment: That was a typo, corrected.  Please do try to grok the point of the answer, you don't stand a chance to set it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Fix pagination problem when printing in C# using HasMorePages.
Explanation about this code: You can add many rows or read from the database to see the result of pagination during printing, for example, I added only two rows to the table manually, which is not paginated because the number of rows is small. Add many rows manually or insert information from the database into the grid view. This is an example:

```
int currentPage = 1;
int rowsPerPage = 36; //Number of rows per page
int rowIndex = 0;

void pdoc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int x = 5, y = 5; //Drawing start position
        int rowMargin = 0; //Spacing between lines

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dgvHesaab.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing; //Text with more lines in a row.
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeight = 40; //40=row height. Text with more lines in a row.

        dgvHesaab.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;

        int rowCount = dgvHesaab.Rows.Count; //Get the number of rows
        int pageCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(rowCount) / Convert.ToDouble(rowsPerPage)));

        //Set header content of columns
        for (int j = this.dgvHesaab.Columns.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 132, dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height); //132 = width in row
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, rect);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
            if (this.dgvHesaab.Columns[j].HeaderText != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this.dgvHesaab.Columns[j].HeaderText, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, rect, sf);
            }
            x += rect.Width;
        }

        x = 5;
        y += dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height + rowMargin;
        //Set the content of the lines
        while (rowIndex < dgvHesaab.Rows.Count)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgvHesaab.Rows[rowIndex];
            if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
            {
                for (int j = this.dgvHesaab.Columns.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[j];
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 132, dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height); //132 = width in row
                    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
                    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
                    if (cell.Value != null)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.Value.ToString(), new Font("Tahoma", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, rect, sf);
                    }
                    x += rect.Width;
                }
                x = 5;
                y += dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height + rowMargin;
            }
            rowIndex++;

            //Print a new page if necessary
            if (rowIndex % rowsPerPage == 0 || rowIndex == dgvHesaab.Rows.Count)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = (currentPage < pageCount);
                currentPage++;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}

   
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Begin , Adding a row to the gridView(dgvHesaab) 
        ///<summary>
        ///For example, the name of our Grid View is dgvHesaab
        ///Retrieving data from a database or manually inserting data for a row. 
        ///</summary>

        //add row 1
        dgvHesaab.Rows.Add(new object[]
        {
            "Row 1 : Item 1",
            "Row 1 : Item 2",
            "Row 1 : Item 3",
            "Row 1 : Item 4",
            "Row 1 : Item 5",
            "Row 1 : Item 6",
        });

        //add row 2
        dgvHesaab.Rows.Add(new object[]
        {
            "Row 2 : Item 1",
            "Row 2 : Item 2",
            "Row 2 : Item 3",
            "Row 2 : Item 4",
            "Row 2 : Item 5",
            "Row 2 : Item 6",
        });
        //End , Adding a row to the gridView(dgvHesaab)  

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dgvHesaab.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing; //Text with more lines in a row.
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeight = 40; //40=row height. Text with more lines in a row.

        dgvHesaab.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;

        //Begin Print
        PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog();
        pDialog.AllowCurrentPage = false;
        pDialog.AllowPrintToFile = false;
        pDialog.AllowSelection = false;
        pDialog.AllowSomePages = false;
        pDialog.PrintToFile = false;
        pDialog.ShowHelp = false;
        pDialog.ShowNetwork = false;
        if (pDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument pdoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
            pdoc.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);
            pdoc.DocumentName = "Print Title";
            pdoc.PrinterSettings = pDialog.PrinterSettings;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings = pDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(100, 100, 100, 100);
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169);
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false; //Landscape
            //pdoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = 3;
            PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            printPreviewDialog1.Document = pdoc;
            pdoc.Print(); //No preview  
            //printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog(); //printPreview
        }
        //End Print
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```